# cannot create android package: NO ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH set in make spec

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

I tried to create qt quick 2 application for android. its building perfectly but when i run the project it gives me following issues.

```
Cannot create Android package: NO ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH set in make spec
Error while building/deploying project ProjectName (kit: Android for x86 (GCC 4.6 Qt 5.2.1))
When executing step 'Package for Android'
```

I downloaded qt for android, android sdk and also the ndk. setting up kits and qt versions are also done.

why do i get this issue?

Comment: I think it would be simpler if you could paste the sample code with the project file, the command(s) you run, etc.

Comment: which **Android architecture** you want to port to ?